# WSO2 IS Fail switching user store to JDBC

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to switch the user store to JDBC:
[user_store]
#type = "database"

I'm using wso2is 5.11.0 and Postgres

When the server start I get this exception:

```
postgres_1  | 2023-03-08 13:47:34.366 UTC [34] ERROR:  null value 

in column "um_user_id" of relation "um_user" violates not-null constraint
postgres_1  | 2023-03-08 13:47:34.366 UTC [34] DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, admin, mS4tQK85H4vAYbwiepeS4DKMq8zk4x0P8MZQvOFFkDY=, Ep+z085KBdCe/G0IObVXFA==, f, 2023-03-08 13:47:34.365, -1234).
postgres_1  | 2023-03-08 13:47:34.366 UTC [34] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO UM_USER (UM_USER_NAME, UM_USER_PASSWORD, UM_SALT_VALUE, UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE, UM_CHANGED_TIME, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
wso2is_1    | [2023-03-08 13:47:34,375] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} - nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
wso2is_1    |   at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:404)
```

Answer (score 1):

The user store config you have shared in the description is wrong. WSO2 IS 5.11.0 use the new schema where the `UM_USER_ID` column is present in the `UM_USER` table. If you have used the dbscripts within the product to setup the database, you need to have the database type as `database_unique_id`. Please refer to the [Configuring a JDBC User Store](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/configuring-a-jdbc-user-store/#configuring-the-internal-database-as-a-jdbc-user-store) for IS 5.11.0 for more information.

```ini
[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"
```